# Posting Zip Files over HTTP No Longer Opening in Win 7 Zip Program

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload, zip

I have two bits of code. One which uploads a zipfile and a server which saves the upload to the drive. My problem is I upload a zip file which opens fine in the windows 7 default zipping program, but when I try to open it from the webserver it was posted too it won't open anymore with the error:

Windows cannot open the folder. The compressed zipped folder 'blah' is invalid.

**Note1: The file opens completely fine in WinRar or other zip programs.**

**Note2: The original file and the file on the server are the exact same size on disk but the size of the one of the server is 200ish bytes bigger**

Here is the code for uploading zips:

```
        public static String UploadFile(String url, String filePath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    byte[] result = client.UploadFile(url, filePath);

                    UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
                    string response = enc.GetString(result);

                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webException)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webException.Response as HttpWebResponse;

                return (httpWebResponse == null) ? webException.Message : httpWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Here is the code on the server which saves the incoming file (exists in the page load of a .NET C# aspx page):

```
        private void SaveZipFile()
        {
            string fileName;
            string zipPath;

            fileName = GenerateFileName();

            zipPath = _hhDescriptor.GetDirectory(path => Server.MapPath(("./" + _serviceName + "\\" + path)) + "\\" + fileName + ".zip");        


        if (!Directory.Exists(zipPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipPath));
        }

        Request.SaveAs(zipPath, false);

        logger.Trace(string.Format("ManualUpload: Successfully saved uploaded zip file to {0}", zipPath));
    }
```

Any ideas / or suggestions as possible places this could be breaking would be greatly appreciated!. I am probably saving some other random stuff along with the zip file.

**UPDATE 1:**

When I open the server's zip file in notepad it contains

> -----------------------8cd8d0e69a0670b Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="file"; filename="filename.zip"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream

So my question is how to save the zip without capturing the header info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem is using [`HttpRequest.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.saveas.aspx). I suspect that's saving the entire request, including the HTTP headers. Look at the file in a binary file editor and I suspect you'll find the headers at the start.

Use [`HttpRequest.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) to get at files uploaded as part of the request, and [`HttpPostedFile.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) to save the file to disk.

Comment: yeah, came across the answer the same time you posted. Request.Files[0].SaveAs(zipPath); did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the entirety of the request which may have some Multipart MIME separators in it.  I think you need to use [**Request.Files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx).